# php can i set a class property in an external static method called by a non-static method of the class, and if so how?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, properties, static

I have a class method, which calls a static method from a seperate class. is there a way that static method can set a public property of the class which called it? Here is a basic example:

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    public $status;

    public function before() {
        Helper::setStatus();
    }

    public function after() {
        echo $this->status;
    }

}

class Helper {

    public static function setStatus() {
        parent()->status = "new";
    }

}

$myclass = new MyClass();
$myclass->before();
$myclass->after(); //would hopefully echo "new"
```

The `parent()` method is just a placeholder for however you would actually do it; I know that `MyClass` is not the parent of `Helper`.

**Is this possible? Am I maybe come at this issue with the wrong approach?**

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to pass in an instance of the class to the static method. Which inside a method could just be `$this`

Example:

```
class MyClass {

    public $status;

    public function before() {
        Helper::setStatus($this);
    }

    public function after() {
        echo $this->status;
    }

}

class Helper {

    public static function setStatus($instance) {
        $instance->status = "new";
    }

}

$myclass = new MyClass();
$myclass->before();
$myclass->after(); //would hopefully echo "new"

//you could also set the status from outside by calling the static method
//and passing in your instance.
Helper::setStatus($myclass); //same as calling before.
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zW2etr

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance of MyClass to Helper class can access by `$this`

> **Note:**   If you pass the instance of any class means, it will pass in
>   `Call By Reference` default.

[**Live demo**](http://codepad.org/uYX6Cf3n)